# Forcefully select <input> filed using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm just working with `d3.js`. I just selected an input field using d3.js. I need to mark an input field as selected, so that I can copy the inputs content to the clipboard.
This is what I have so far:

```
 <input class="input" val="content">
```

By using jquery we can do it like this:

```
var inputField = jQuery(".input");
inputField.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

How can i done it using d3.js:

```
d3.select(".input").*Which function to use?*
```

Which function can be used to forcefully select the input field?

Answer (score 1):

To select an input-element you can use javascript's native element.focus() function or if you want to automatically select all the text inside it you can use the element.select() function. Like:

`document.getElementsByClassName("input-field")[0].focus()`

But if you insist on using d3.js then you could do this too:

`d3.select(".input-field")._groups[0][0].focus()`

Fair warning, I haven't used d3.js before so the d3.js way is probably not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you're getting. 
If it's the first instance you can try 

`var myInputName = d3.select("input");`